# IsPressed trigger works when False, doesn't work when True

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, triggers

I have multiple styles in my applications. Here's the one this question is about:

```
<Style x:Key="RoundCornerSmart" TargetType="{x:Type vk:SmartButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type vk:SmartButton}">
                <Border CornerRadius="8" BorderBrush="#006AB6" BorderThickness="1" Name="border">
                    <Grid x:Name="grid">
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>

                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                LightGray
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>

                    <Trigger Property="IsPressed" Value="False">
                        <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                White
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>

    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18" />
    <Setter Property="Height" Value="62" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="62" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black" />
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Black" />
</Style>
```

SmartButton is a class which extends the Button class, it's a Button user-control.

```
 <vk:SmartButton HoldCommand="{Binding Path=ClickCommand}" EnableClickHold="True" MillisecondsToWait="1000" x:Name="key_U" Content="U" Grid.Column="8" Style="{DynamicResource RoundCornerSmart}"/>
```

When the smart button isn't pressed - its background is white, which is how it's supposed to be. However, when it's pressed, the background doesn't change. It's still white. What am I doing wrong? Why is the IsPressed not triggered?

EDIT:

When I comment the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method, it works.

Here's what happens in that method:

```
if (EnableClickHold)
        {
            Timer = new DispatcherTimer(DispatcherPriority.Normal, this.Dispatcher)
            {
                Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(MillisecondsToWait)
            };
            Timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;
            Timer.IsEnabled = true;
            Timer.Start();
            e.Handled = true;
        }
```

Comment: What exactly does KeyPressedCommand? Does this command have some CanExecute method? Try to check if the button is enabled.

Comment: @user2250152 I removed that, it was unused. However on the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonUp I have a few calls to simple methods.

Comment: @user2250152 When I comment the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method, the background works.

Comment: Try to set the DisptacherTimer priority to Render or Background.

Comment: @Riccardo I found out what the problem is and answered the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was:

```
e.Handled=true;
```

That line in the OnPreviewMouseLeftButtonDown method. I don't know why though. When I commented it, the background was set to LightGrey, it worked.

Comment: Yes, if you set e.Handled = true then mouseevent is not propagated to BaseButton class which sets IsPressed = true